# How to change jekyll's default include folder

Tags: include, jekyll

I know I can change the default layout directory by specifying the new directory in _config.yaml like this:

```
layouts: "templates"
```

Doing the same for the includes directory doesn't seem to be working. I cannot find any documentation for it either on the jekyll website. Here is what i tried

```
includes: "partials"
```

Its not working though. It would be great if anyone could help out with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No way, it's hard coded in Jekyll::Tags::IncludeTag.

You can try to override the class or [make a feature request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) to the Jekyll team if you want to be able to change include directory in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Base on this [doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#including-files-relative-to-another-file), you can also choose to include file fragments relative to the current file:

```
{% include_relative somedir/footer.html %}
```